# Rails 3 subdomain routing and URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I am running into routing issues regarding subdomains in Rails 3 when porting from Rails 2.3.x + gem subdomain_routes. With the subdomain_routes gem I was able to map routes easily by model like the following:

```
# config/routes.rb
map.subdomain :model => :site do |site|
  resources :pages
end
```

This would generate url helpers, like `site_pages_url` and could be used like this:

```
# console
@site = Site.find_by_subdomain(“yehuda”)
app.site_pages_url(@site) => http://yehuda.example.com/pages
app.site_page_url(@site, @page) => http://yehuda.example.com/page/routes-rock
```

In Rails 3 this roughly would translate to:

```
# config/routes.rb
class SiteSubdomain  
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www' &&
      request.params[:site_id].present?
  end  
end

Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sites do
    constraints(SiteSubdomain) do
      resources :pages
    end
  end
end
```

and overloading the standard url_for should basically work like in subdomain_routes:

```
module UrlFor

  def with_subdomain(subdomain)  
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")  
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?  
    [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join  
  end  

  def url_for(options = nil)  
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)  
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))  
    end  
    super  
  end

end
ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor.send(:include, UrlFor)
```

However, the url helpers still do not generate the correct URL like `site_pages_url(@site) #=> http://www.example.com/pages`, instead of the expected `http://yehuda.example.com/pages`

Comment: Do you have any news on this question?

Comment: @chinshr Any news or update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You've named the class as

```
SiteSubdomain
```

That effectively means, your routes should have SiteSubdomain instead of Subdomain. Modify to

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sites do
    constraints(SiteSubdomain) do
      resources :kases
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I just corrected the mistake in my question. The problem is that I still don't seem to be able to generate a correct route, e.g. `site_pages_url(@site) #=> http://yehuda.example.com/pages`